# Desplegable material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, style

Estoy desarrollando una app en React, javascript y utilizando el paquete de elementos de material-ui para los diferentes elementos de la página. En este caso el desplegabe para seleccionar una opción u otra.

Tengo un desplegable de la siguiente forma:

```
<Select
   id="season"
   value={season}
   onChange={(event) => { setSeason(event.target.value) }}
   style={{ marginRight: '10px' }}>
      {
       seasons.map((season) => <MenuItem key={season.id} value={season}>{season.name} 
                              </MenuItem>)
     
       }
</Select>
```

El elemento Select

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    fade,
    withStyles
} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import InputBase from '@material-ui/core/InputBase';

const SelectInput = withStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        'label + &': {
            marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
        },
    },
    input: {
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: '36px',
        borderRadius: 4,
        position: 'relative',
        backgroundColor: '#fcfcfb',
        border: '1px solid #e2e2e1',
        fontSize: 16,
        padding: '10px 26px 10px 12px',
        transition: theme.transitions.create(['border-color', 'box-shadow']),
        // Use the system font instead of the default Roboto font.
        fontFamily: [
            '-apple-system',
            'BlinkMacSystemFont',
            '"Segoe UI"',
            'Roboto',
            '"Helvetica Neue"',
            'Arial',
            'sans-serif',
            '"Apple Color Emoji"',
            '"Segoe UI Emoji"',
            '"Segoe UI Symbol"',
        ].join(','),
        '&:focus': {
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            boxShadow: `${fade('#777', 0.30)} 0 0 0 2px`,
            borderRadius: 4
        },
        focused: {},
    }
}))(InputBase);

export default function RedditTextField(props) {
    return (
        <div style={props.style ? props.style : null}>
            {
                props.label ?
                    <InputLabel style={{ marginBottom: '5px', marginTop: '-20px' }} id={props.id + '-label'}>
                        {props.label}
                    </InputLabel>
                    : null
            }
            <FormControl fullWidth>
                <Select
                    id={props.id}
                    value={props.value}
                    onChange={props.onChange}
                    input={<SelectInput />}
                >
                    {props.children}
                </Select>
            </FormControl>
        </div >
    );
}
```

El problema es que la lista que tengo que representar es muy larga y se ve muy feo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay alguna forma de limitar la longitud del selector para que no salgan todos los elementos de golpe y pueda desplazarme por los elementos? Actualmente el desplegable se extiende en función del tamaño de ventana hasta el borde inferior de la ventana.

Muchas gracias de antemano :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente lo he conseguido con lo siguiente:

Justo antes de la línea "export default function RedditTextField(props) {"
he añadido lo siguiente:

```
const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 5.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250
    }
  }
};
```

Estoy especificando la separación entre los elementos, la altura de cada elemento y declaro que la altura máxima del desplegable sea "ITEM_HEIGHT * 5.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP".

Finalmente, en el FormControl he añadido la propiedad MenuProps.

```
<FormControl fullWidth>
            <Select
                id={props.id}
                value={props.value}
                onChange={props.onChange}
                MenuProps={MenuProps}
                input={<SelectInput />}
            >
                {props.children}
            </Select>
        </FormControl>
```

Fuente: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-9fodm?file=/demo.js:2279-2300